# Unable to call Talend Open Studio tContextLoad in query

Tags: etl, talend, talend-mdm

I'm trying to a variable I created from the tContextLoad_1 to perform a query. I've successfully loaded the data into the context using tContextLoad_1. For the key I used date and for the value I used the max date returned from the query. 
However when I try and use the context in the query I get an error message that date cannot be resolved (see error below). I'm calling the context value as context.date, not sure if this is how context should be used in the query. Any points will help.

Thanks.

**WorkFlow**
[image]

**Context Query**

[image]

**Error Message**

[image]

Comment: Show us more detail like context variables in your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your context variable "date" is declared in your "context" view for this job (careful, it is case sensitive). This error usually means that the variable is not declared in the job.

Comment: Thanks Corentin! That was it, It worked! I went through few examples online they didn't mention that I had to define the context variable.